# Carousel not showing all images?

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I need to create an slider image gallery that works in all devices, large and small. I've followed a tutorial and downloaded the files provided and kept only the carousel part I need. [This is the tutorial](https://azmind.com/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-items/). However, when adding the code to my website, something is failing, I can only see one image at a time, instead of the entire row of pictures.

This is what it should look like based on the tutorial:
[image]

This is how it shows on my website:
[image]

From the files I downloaded from the tutorial, the only ones I need are `animation.css`, and the carousel script from the `scripts.js` file.

[Here's my codepen](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/KKpYjNW).

HTML:

```html
<div class="top-content" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 active">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img1" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img2" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img3" style="border: 1px solid green;">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img4" style="border: 1px solid purple;">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img5" style="border: 1px solid cyan;">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img6" style="border: 1px solid orange;">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img7">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img8">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$('#carousel-example').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

    /*
        CC 2.0 License Iatek LLC 2018
        Attribution required
    */
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 5;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;

    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Post a working example demonstrating your issue

Comment: I have updated and am showing my code.

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself. Don't link external websites. Links can become invalid in the future. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're missing the css from that tutorial.